# How to make netcat send HTTP headers over multiple TCP segments?

Tags: http, tcp, netcat

I am trying to simulate "HTTP headers spanning multiple TCP segments" as mentioned here - http://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP_Preferences. 
How can this be done using netcat? Are there any examples you might be able to point me to to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Netcat isn't really the right tool for this job, but an easy way to make the headers span segments is just to make them long enough. Eventually, they won't fit in a single segment.

The packet size may be 1500 octets (normal Ethernet) or more than 9000 octets (Ethernet with jumbo frames). You'll want some actual network, packet processing with localhost is often optimized.

(For the proper tools for this, you probably want to ask on Severfault or Security.SE, as they're normally used for firewall testing)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, netcat doesn't seem to have this option to segment the data in different tcp packets. After some googling, found out the test case  at http://redmine.lighttpd.net/attachments/522/web_test.c, which seems to fit the bill.